# jquery validator plugin code is not working against multiple values

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I need to invalidate spammers entering "gmail", "hotmail", "yahoo", "rediff" addresses. And allow only business emails. I'm using the popular validator plugin: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

So here is the code that checks against a single value and works:

```
  jQuery.validator.addMethod("biz", function(value, element) {
    var email = value;
    return !(email.indexOf("gmail") > -1);
  }, "Only business emails allowed");
```

Here is the html:

```
  <label>Email Address <em class="formee-req">*</em></label>
  <input class="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Business Email Only" type="text" name="email">
  <span></span>
```

And then the call to the plugin:

```
   $('.basic-form').validate(
   {

    rules: {
      email : {
        biz: true
      }
    }
```

The above code works. So now when I try to validate against multiple values like so:

```
  jQuery.validator.addMethod("biz", function(value, element) {
    var invalid_email_domains = ["gmail", "hotmail", "yahoo", "rediff"];
    var email = value;
    $.each(invalid_email_domains, function (index, invalid_domain) {
       if(email.indexOf(invalid_domain) > -1) {
          return true;
       } else {
          return false;
       };
    });

  }, "Only business emails allowed");
```

It doesn't validate for other values i.e. I always get the error "*Only business emails allowed*" no matter what value I enter. What am I doing wrong? I try flipping the Boolean but it just keeps returning the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked:

```
  jQuery.validator.addMethod("biz", function(value, element) {
    var invalid_email_domains = ["gmail", "hotmail", "yahoo", "rediff"],
    email = value,
    isValid = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < invalid_email_domains.length; i++) {
      if (email.indexOf(invalid_email_domains[i]) > -1) {
        // console.log("invalid biz address found");
        isValid = false;
        break;
      }
    };

    return isValid;

  }, "Only business emails allowed");
```

Looks like I needed to set a boolean first and then break out of the loop when the wrong value was found.